# If $f(x)$ is increasing on the real line, then $f(-x)$ is decreasing on the real line,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to show that if $f(x)$ is increasing on the real line, then $f(-x)$ is decreasing on the real line.

My attempt:

For $x_1 < x_2$,

$$f(x_1) < f(x_2)$$

Now $-x_1 > -x_2$, and

$$ f(-x_2) < f(-x_1)$$

which seems to show that $f(-x)$ is also increasing ...

Where have I gone wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Essentially you are looking at the composite function $f(-x)$ ($f$ with $x\rightarrow-x$) is decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clearer looking, set $g(x)=f(-x)$, so $x_{1}<x_{2}$ implies $g(x_{2})<g(x_{1})$, $g$ is decreasing.

Comment: You have proved the result, can you see that?

Comment: So fixed $x_{1}<x_{2}$, hence $-x_{2}<-x_{1}$, now we use the assumption that $f$ is increasing to get $f(-x_{2})<f(-x_{1})$, so we conclude that $g(x_{2})<g(x_{1})$, essentially I am re-writing your reasoning.